# how to parse ONLY integer values in SQL

Tags: sql, parsing, integer, int

I want to be able to parse only integer values from a column in a database such that my query looks like the following:

```
SELECT x
FROM database
WHERE x is like int
```

where X is a column in a database that would have the following values:

```
x
TRUE
FALSE
8.9
234
TY09B-XYZ
```

and my query would only return

```
x
8.9
234
```

thanks!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: just note `8.9` is not integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQLServer, and assuming you mean numbers as opposed to just integers (8.9 is not an integer)

```
SELECT x
FROM table
WHERE isnumeric(x) = 1
```

More information on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx